# Atualizar dados com Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, console-application

Estou com um problema que quando tenho esse código abaixo:

```
 public static String GravarNoBDFildes(List<Fildes> dados)
 {
         try
          {
             Console.WriteLine("Começando o processamento");
             var inseridos = new List<Fildes>();

             using (var fildesContext = new FildesContext())
             {
                    fildesContext.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;
                    dados.ForEach(x => {   
                      var retorno = fildesContext.Fildess.Add(x);
                      inseridos.Add(retorno);
                    });                    

                    fildesContext.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
                    fildesContext.SaveChanges();
             }
             Console.WriteLine("Dados inseridos no Banco" + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dados));
             return "Processamento foi concluido";
          }
 }
```

Me remete esse erro quando inicio o projeto console:

> "Processamento Falhou, com o erro: An error occurred while updating
>   the entries. See the inner exception for details.".

O que seria esse erro e como posso corrigi-lo por favor.

Comment: comece adicionando um `catch(Exception ex){throw ex;}` depois do seu try e debugue o seu código linha por linha...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debugue o código e dê uma olhada no InnerException, dentro dele tem uma lista de erros que foram gerados durante o comando lá você vai encontrar o que deu errado.